# Synaptic on startup

Tags: startup, xfce

I'm using Xfce 4.10 on Ubuntu 13.10. When I reboot my computer, it always opens the Synaptic package manager. How can I modify some starting script such that it won't open it at the startup?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  Go to Settings Manager, and then go to

[image]

Session and Startup

[image]

Then go to Application Autostart, and see if Synaptic package manager is listed, and Uncheck it.

[image]

Also look under the Session tab, and change the Restart Style.

[image]

Comment: There is no "Synaptic" option in the list.

Comment: Your answer forced me to stop writing my answer in between, because I was going to suggest the same thing.. You described it wonderfully! In addition, I want to suggest to go to Session tab in the same window and search for the Synaptic and click **Quit Program** :)